# Replace a short length of triaxial cable with a PCB transmission line

Tags: pcb-design, rf, transmission-line, coax

I am working on a project that benefits from a short (~1") length of triaxial cable. At first I was skeptical that the cable would have any effect given its short length, but the performance is definitely improved using the cable. The problem is the cable with its associated connectors is tricky to assemble. I am wondering if it's possible to recreate the effect of the cable with a microstrip (or coplanar waveguide or something else?) on a PCB. Assembly would be much easier and less error prone if I could solder the connectors directly to the ends of a small PCB.

I understand how to use a transmission line calculator (like the one built in to KiCad) to create a microstrip line, but I can't determine how I will match the impedance of both shields of the cable or if it matters.

I have measured the impedance from the inner conductor of the cable to the inner shield as 80 ohm and from the inner conductor to the outer shield as 100 ohm. I don't know if the inner conductor to outer shield impedance matters, and I don't know if I should measure and give significance to the impedance between the inner and outer shields.

My current plan is to create an 80 ohm coplanar wave guide with ground plane to replicate the inner conductor and inner shield impedance and just add conductors on the periphery of the PCB to connect the outer shield and not attempt to replicate the 100 ohm impedance of that part of the cable.

Does this sound like a reasonable plan?

Comment: This might work. But what is the source and destination impedances? How many sources and destinations? What frequencies? A diagram or schematic would help us understand better. Please edit the question with any further info.

Comment: The destination is another ~2 m of the same cable on the other side of a panel mount connector that is terminated by a capacitive sensor, and the source is some kind of simple capacitance sensing circuit that I don't fully understand. I don't know how to determine the impedance of the source and destination. The frequencies are on the order of 50 kHz. I'll see if I can put together a schematic.